# ctrl + LMB press the number 4 depending on if var = 1 or not

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make ctrl + LMB press the number 4 depending on if var = 1 or not and to toggle var between 0 and 1.

```
var := 0

if(var==1)
{
ctrl&LButton::4
var = 0
return
}

else
{
ctrl&LButton::
var = 1
return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to toggle between 0 and 1 > [send 4] and [send ctrl&LButton]

Then you can try this code.

```
; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
; ^ = Ctrl
; # = Win (Windows logo key)

a := 0 

; toggle between [send 4] and [send ctrl&LButton]
;a = 0   => send 4
;a = 1   => send ctrl&LButton

^LButton::
if (a=1)
{
send {ctrl Down}{LButton Down}{ctrl Up}{LButton Up}
a := 0
}else{
send 4
a := 1
}
return
```

Comment: It almost works, it types the 4 but the click does not work.

Comment: @Althaen If you want to do with var 1 to send ctrl&LButton - i did reedit the Answer - And I Hope you will like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$^LButton::Send, % (var := !var) ? "{LButton}" : 4
```

Comment: Not quite what I meant, I want it to toggle between a normal click and pressing 4.